# Check if key/value is in JSON

Tags: python, json

With this code

```
import sense
import json

sense.api_key = '...'
node = sense.Node.retrieve('........')
feed = node.feeds.retrieve('presence')

events = feed.events.list(limit=1)

result = json.dumps(events,indent=1)
print result
```

I get a JSON-Feed like this:

```
{
 "links": {...}, 
 "objects": [
  {
   "profile": "GenStandard", 
   "feedUid": ".....", 
   "gatewayNodeUid": ".....", 
   "dateServer": "2015-02-28T09:57:22.337034", 
   "geometry": null, 
   "data": {
    "body": "Present", 
    "code": 200
   }, 
   "signal": "-62", 
   "dateEvent": "2015-02-28T09:57:22.000000", 
   "type": "presence", 
   "payload": "2", 
   "nodeUid": "....."
  }
 ], 
 "totalObjects": 875, 
 "object": "list"
}
```

How can I check if 'body' is 'present' (or 'code' is '200')? My script should return TRUE or FALSE

**UPDATE**

If I add this code as proposed in the answers it works fine:

```
d=json.loads(result)
def checkJson(jsonContents):
    bodyFlag = True if "body" in jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"] and jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"]["body"] == "Present" else False

    return bodyFlag

print checkJson(d)
```

Comment: That is because you are dumping the json, you should either use `d=json.loads(result)` or just load the json first.

Comment: Thx, that was the solution!

Comment: no worries, you also need to use `in` to find the  if `'body'` is i the dict, the other answers are looking for a value `Present` which I imagine is not what you want. I presume by `present` you mean exists

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should also maybe check if the body key is actually there.

```
def checkJson(jsonContents):
    bodyFlag = True if "body" in jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"] and jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"]["body"] == "Present" else False
    codeFlag = True if "code" in jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"] and jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"]["code"] == 200 else False

    return bodyFlag or codeFlag

print checkJson(result)
```

Comment: You are going down the same branch - __jsonContents["objects"][0]["data"]__ 4 times! In such a case, it is customary to assign a value to an intermediate variable. And you use ternary operator to assign a boolean value! And if 1st condition is _True_ - no need to evaluate the 2nd

Answer (score 3):

```
d = json.loads(results)
objs = d["objects"][0]
# see if any code is either == 200 or "body" is a key in the subdict
return any(x for x in (objs["data"]["code"] == 200,"body" in objs["data"]))
```

Comment: Why use _any_ just for 2 values? Simple _or_ will do