# Cannot check if key exists for complex JSON object in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a json data like:

```
{    
    "cse_thumbnail": [   
     {    
          "width": "188",
          "height": "268",
          "src": "http://abc.dk"
        }     
    ],    
    "metatags": [    
     {    
      "referrer": "origin-when-cross-origin",
      "og:image": "http://def.dk"
     }    
    ],    
    "cse_image": [    
     {    
      "src": "http://ghi.dk"
     }    
    ]    
   }
```

There are 3 array lists coming in the JSON. I want to check if the corresponding keys are existing when I'm getting the response:

cse_thumbnail

metatags

cse_image

I'm tried all the key:value pair check in python like (hasattr, key in list etc) which are not working at all.

Please help to get it resolved.

Comment: please share you python code...

Comment: Please check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780547/check-if-key-value-is-in-json

Comment: Did you use: `json.loads` on the JSON file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if key/value is in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28780547/check-if-key-value-is-in-json)

Comment: Yes, I use json.loads

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if a key is present

```
import json

with open('data.json') as thing:
    data = json.load(thing)
    keys = ('cse_thumbnail', 'metatags', 'cse_image')
    for key in keys:
        print(key in data)
```

Comment: I just implemented the code and it returned 'false' for all of them:
                                                                                                                
2017-06-23T11:53:41.804312+00:00 app[web.1]: False
2017-06-23T11:53:41.804314+00:00 app[web.1]: False
2017-06-23T11:53:41.804317+00:00 app[web.1]: False

Comment: Thanks, your comment has saved my life. I finally changed few lines in the code and now it finally working after two days of headbanging.  The JSON object was coming with u_string. I removed them and now they are getting working fine.