# Verify JSON file matches TypeScript Interface

Tags: json, typescript

i have a `config.json` file

```
{
  "profiler": {
    "port": 8001,
    "profilerCache": {
      "allowedOriginsRegex": ["^http:\/\/localhost:8080$", "i"]
    }
  },
  "database": {
    "uri": "mongodb+srv://...",
    "dbName": "profiler",
    "collectionName": "profiles"
  }
}
```

at build time, i want to see errors if the json structure doesn't match my interface for it

```
export interface Config {
  port: number
  profilerCache: {
    allowedOriginsRegex: [string, string]
  }
  database: {
    uri: string
    dbName: string
    collectionName: string
  }
}
```

what's the simplest way to accomplish type safety for my json files?

Comment: You can create a temp file like `let x: Config = your-json` and compile it, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57942560/989121

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the `JSON` object to a variable of the interface type will show structural errors.

```
export interface Config {
  port: number
  profilerCache: {
    allowedOriginsRegex: [string, string]
  }
  database: {
    uri: string
    dbName: string
    collectionName: string
  }
}

let jsonConfig: Config = {
  "port_error": 8001,  // Error: Object literal may only specify known properties, and '"port_error"' does not exist in type 'Config'.
  "profilerCache": {
    "allowedOriginsRegex": ["^http:\/\/localhost:8080$", "i"]
  },
  "database": {
    "uri": "mongodb+srv://...",
    "dbName": "profiler",
    "collectionName": "profiles"
  }
}
```

See [**Typescript Playground Example**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQiXQQHM4BvAKDjklgC44kBXAWwCM0a6oISANmnw4AFsCbVatTAIEQA7sAAmAeShlkAZwBKwUqCYBtLTA1JSAGjinzpALo8Avj2WYYmDpi0TKPWiwaTLbIpP5wyhwAcphsviEW4dgQcsDYMAhEMXHBZqHOVC5UQvAAVlpEhMRkTFUk5AC8frQARPQwAPpofFAtTAAcAAyDAIyWPG18gsJiwH3N0i2y8kpqGqTaegYg80YtAHqiMDBgDAA6APSX8tiyohCmDENDACQt1i0ILY60TuOtbg8Xh88yki0CXyYLTYRFIEEiAGotFAAG4MC4XAB02Pe4RakWycyhYCmCCEvX+i2SqXSmSQhPmk34ZOAWhaBSKQA)

Comment: i'd like my `config.json` to actually be an json file — not a typescript file which contains some json — i'm hoping the authoritative `config.json` can be ingested/manipulated by other tools which are familiar with json (but not typescript)

Comment: @ChaseMoskal If you want to verify the JSON structure at **runtime**, see [**Check if an object implements an interface at runtime with TypeScript**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33800497/1164465).